# Error ending tags JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert this JQuery Code:

But it throws errors, what's wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  });
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
$(function() {
    $('.jcarouselimgs').jcarousel({
        // Core configuration goes here
    });

    $('.arrowimg-prev').jcarouselControl({
        target: '-=1'
    });

    $('.arrowimg-next').jcarouselControl({
        target: '+=1'
    });
     });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are closing the `document.ready` immediately after opening.

Comment: remove }); after ready and of last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {

        $('.jcarouselimgs').jcarousel({
            // Core configuration goes here
        });

        $('.arrowimg-prev').jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

        $('.arrowimg-next').jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=1'
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $('.jcarouselimgs').jcarousel({
        // Core configuration goes here
    });

    $('.arrowimg-prev').jcarouselControl({
        target: '-=1'
    });

    $('.arrowimg-next').jcarouselControl({
        target: '+=1'
    });
   } //close if


 }); // end document ready
```

Comment: And now why is throwing me error?      if ($(window).width() < 640) {
        $('.jcarouselimgs').jcarousel({
          $('.arrowimg-prev').jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=2'
        });
               $('.arrowimg-next').jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=2'
        });
        });